# Proving the validity of a more efficient algorithm than the extended euclidean algorithm for relative primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I read in a book that there is a more efficient algorithm (which uses less storage in computers) than the extended euclidean algorithm in the case of relative primes. 
As it appears in the attached photo, I could prove that if P_t = a and Q_t = b, then it would be a valid algorithm. But, unfortunately, I can't prove that this recursion will eventually yield "a" and "b". So, anyone can tell me why it works??
[image]

Comment: Hesham What book would that be?

Comment: @JeanMarie   I've been meaning to ask:  if I were to type in your first name (without an at sign)  would that be Jean   or Jean Marie? For me, just Will....

Comment: @Will Jagy My first name is the whole composite Jean-Marie...

Comment: Jean-Marie, Thank   you.

Comment: @WillJagy an introduction to mathematical cryptography

Comment: preview  https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Cryptogr/z2SBIhmqMBMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction

Answer (score 1):

This is what you get by applying continued fractions to  finding $\gcd(a,b) $  and  producing a Bezout identity $ax+by = \gcd(a,b) .$  Consecutive convergents in a continued fraction  have the little 2 by 2 cross product  equal to $\pm 1 $

On page 18 they find the gcd of 73 and 25:

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \gcd( 73, 25 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 73 }{ 25 } = 2 +  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 } $$
$$ \frac{ 25 }{ 23 } = 1 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 23 } $$
$$ \frac{ 23 }{ 2 } = 11 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$
$$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 & & 2 & & 1 & & 11 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 35 }{ 12 }   & &   \frac{ 73 }{ 25 }  
 \end{array}
 $$
$$  $$
$$ 73 \cdot 12 - 25 \cdot 35 = 1 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \gcd( 100, 67 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 100 }{ 67 } = 1 +  \frac{ 33 }{ 67 } $$
$$ \frac{ 67 }{ 33 } = 2 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 33 } $$
$$ \frac{ 33 }{ 1 } = 33 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 2 & & 33 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 100 }{ 67 }  
 \end{array}
 $$
$$  $$
$$ 100 \cdot 2 - 67 \cdot 3 = -1 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \gcd( 1001, 43 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 1001 }{ 43 } = 23 +  \frac{ 12 }{ 43 } $$
$$ \frac{ 43 }{ 12 } = 3 +  \frac{ 7 }{ 12 } $$
$$ \frac{ 12 }{ 7 } = 1 +  \frac{ 5 }{ 7 } $$
$$ \frac{ 7 }{ 5 } = 1 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 } $$
$$ \frac{ 5 }{ 2 } = 2 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$
$$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
 & & 23 & & 3 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 23 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 70 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 93 }{ 4 }   & &   \frac{ 163 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 419 }{ 18 }   & &   \frac{ 1001 }{ 43 }  
 \end{array}
 $$
$$  $$
$$ 1001 \cdot 18 - 43 \cdot 419 = 1 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

The most steps for $a,b$  of a given size happens with consecutive Fibonacci numbers

$$  \gcd( 144, 89 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 144 }{ 89 } = 1 +  \frac{ 55 }{ 89 } $$
$$ \frac{ 89 }{ 55 } = 1 +  \frac{ 34 }{ 55 } $$
$$ \frac{ 55 }{ 34 } = 1 +  \frac{ 21 }{ 34 } $$
$$ \frac{ 34 }{ 21 } = 1 +  \frac{ 13 }{ 21 } $$
$$ \frac{ 21 }{ 13 } = 1 +  \frac{ 8 }{ 13 } $$
$$ \frac{ 13 }{ 8 } = 1 +  \frac{ 5 }{ 8 } $$
$$ \frac{ 8 }{ 5 } = 1 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 } $$
$$ \frac{ 5 }{ 3 } = 1 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 } $$
$$ \frac{ 3 }{ 2 } = 1 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$
$$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 8 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 13 }{ 8 }   & &   \frac{ 21 }{ 13 }   & &   \frac{ 34 }{ 21 }   & &   \frac{ 55 }{ 34 }   & &   \frac{ 144 }{ 89 }  
 \end{array}
 $$
$$  $$
$$ 144 \cdot 34 - 89 \cdot 55 = 1 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

If there was a common factor, this is divided out in a specific way:

$$  \gcd( 1043, 1001 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 1043 }{ 1001 } = 1 +  \frac{ 42 }{ 1001 } $$
$$ \frac{ 1001 }{ 42 } = 23 +  \frac{ 35 }{ 42 } $$
$$ \frac{ 42 }{ 35 } = 1 +  \frac{ 7 }{ 35 } $$
$$ \frac{ 35 }{ 7 } = 5 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 7 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 23 & & 1 & & 5 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 24 }{ 23 }   & &   \frac{ 25 }{ 24 }   & &   \frac{ 149 }{ 143 }  
 \end{array}
 $$
$$  $$
$$ 149 \cdot 24 - 143 \cdot 25 = 1 $$

$$  \gcd( 1043, 1001 ) = 7  $$
$$ 1043 \cdot 24 - 1001 \cdot 25 = 7 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: I don't understand what the values in the table represent, and I am not sure I get how you got from applying the Euclidean algorithm to filling up the table. P.S. I am not familiar with using continued fractions to get the gcd, but I think it is another representation of the Euclidean algorithm

Comment: @HeshamAbdelgawad  on page 18, the book does 73, 25. I have added that example to my answer. Concentrate on page 18

Comment: I don't think you get what I am asking. I don't see why this table will give a and b in the final columns. All you wrote is just some examples. Either that or you are assuming that I know something that I don't actually know.

Comment: @HeshamAbdelgawad  I recommend you just do a few examples yourself,  perhaps  the ones I chose, see if you can write out the part with the quotients and then the entire "box"  as in your book. That is experience for yourself what the final column becomes. Meanwhile, this is the continued fraction for $a/b,$   which is guaranteed finite and guaranteed to result in $a/b$   when in lowest terms. A full proof is a chapter in a continued fractions book. When you are confident with the method and have some time, you can plow through the proof. Please do some examples to begin

Comment: @HeshamAbdelgawad  I think you are asking for a proof that this method is guaranteed to work. Continued fractions are done in Hardy and Wright, for example. The material you want is chapter 10, pages 129-136  in the fifth edition.   In the sixth edition, additional author Andrew Wiles, and your Joseph Silverman is one of the editors

Comment: The method itself is pretty easy. Thy why part is what I wasn't comfortable with. Thank you anyway

Comment: Can you upvote my question, so I get enough reputation to upvote your answer

Comment: I think I have a potential proof of the validity of this algorithm. I am trying to prove it by induction, but I am stuck at the third step. Would you care to help me with it??